# Can someone please assist me with this Ionic Project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to build this project with Ionic and Cordova for Android but I can't figure out why it's complaining about the NPM function.

```html
ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android

[INFO] Looks like @ionic/app-scripts isn't installed in this project.

       This package is required for this command to work properly.

? Install @ionic/app-scripts? Yes
> npm i -D -E @ionic/app-scripts
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_TOKEN}
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:415:13
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at envReplace (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:411:12)
    at parseField (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:389:7)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:330:24
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Conf.add (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:328:23)
    at ConfigChain.addString (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/config-chain/index.js:244:8)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:316:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:61
      throw new Error('npm.load() required')
      ^

Error: npm.load() required
    at Object.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:61:13)
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:18)
    at process.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:485:27)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm i -D -E @ionic/app-scripts exited with exit code 7.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
        information.
```

Comment: Have you tried running your command with the `--verbose` flag to get more information?

Comment: I recently had the exact same problem after trying to install a npm module. Turned out some of my components got upgraded from angular 4 to 6 but not others. Oddly, I couldn't revert back to a version that didn't have that app-scripts error so I ended up upgrading the entire project and it now works again. Not sure if that is the situation you're in but that was my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically npm token needed to be changed, and installed zsh to change the token

Answer (score 0):

Try `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` and then `ionic build android` and lets see if you have any error

Comment: Thanks for the help but it didnt work, figured out the error